# Angular.js: Repeating HTML data list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I have tried applying **[ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)** on angular.js component.
I know that needs to use `ng-repeat`, acutally I don't know how to apply this.

In my case, data is build as HTML document for repeating.
Each of `$ctrl.htmlViews` data like this.

```
<li ...> ... </li> <li ...> ... </li> ... <li ...> ... </li>
```

I want to append these documents in `<ul>` below.

```
<div class="scroll" id="antTalkList" view-type="total
    <ul class="user_list list ng-scope"
        infinite-scroll='$ctrl.loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
        <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.htmlViews"><!-- I don't wanna use this -->
            <ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="item"> </ng-bind-html>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my code snippet of Controller.

```
.component('antList', {
    templateUrl : 'templates/ant-list.html'
    , controller : function AntListController($http, $attrs, $sce){
        var self = this;
        this.htmlViews = [];
        this.loading = false;

        this.loadMore = function(){
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : 'ant/list?pageCount=20&startIndex=' 
                    + $('#antTalkList .user_list li').size()
                    + '&sectionId=' +$attrs.talkType
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                self.htmlViews.push($sce.trustAsHtml(response.data));
            });
        }

    }
})
```

Result of `$http` ajax request, is already built in HTML code like below.

```
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
...
```

I thought a tag having `ng-repat` is repated, so I wrote code like above code. However, I don't want to use `<div ng-repeat= ....></div>`. Because that case, result page will be like this.

```
<ul ...>
  <div>
   <li ...>
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
   <li ...>
    ...
  </div>
</ul>
```

I think this looks awful. How can I repeat whithout additional tag(s) like `div`?

One more problem.

I declared `infinite-scroll='$ctrl.loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='1'` but angular.js doesn't calls `loadMore()` function after loaded(It means, just 1 requests when it's initialized, and no more calls the function).

Comment: You can move `ng-repeat` in <li> tag, it works: `<li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.htmlViews">`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this - replacing `div` with `li`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.htmlViews">
    <ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="item"> </ng-bind-html>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Could also use `ng-bind-html` as an attribute:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.htmlViews" ng-bind-html="item"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there any way without outside tag(s) with ng-bind-html ?

Comment: `item` is built as HTML code already, like `<li></li><li></li> ... `

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible... You just need to follow the below code

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think it is not I want. The `x` have to built in HTML code containing `<li>` elements

Comment: Can u please explain. Do you want to all repeated List Item should be added by dynamically??

Comment: Yes, It shuld be. because it such as scrolling pagination like facebook or twitter.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate htmlViews directly on the 'li' tag

```
<div class="scroll"
    id="antTalkList"
    view-type="total"
    infinite-scroll='$ctrl.loadMore()'
    infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
    <ul class="user_list list ng-scope">
        <li 
            ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.htmlViews" 
            ng-bind-html="item">
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is same Akhaya's answer. the `item` is build already as HTML data. Sorry.

Comment: Are the $ctrl.htmlViews strings in the controller? htmlViews[0] = "<HTML code>";

Comment: Yes, htmlViews[0] ==  '<li>..'

Comment: I've modified the plnkr provided by Angular documentation https://plnkr.co/edit/TTBH8Hcg7QPIVCCmB4CF?p=preview
Is this what you need? The "items" are strings containing HTML code

Comment: Oh, please see this. https://plnkr.co/edit/Ij1i4jleeXw019Q2as6e?p=preview , I would be shown as `result.html`. Thank you kindly answer @OriolVives

Comment: I'm not really sure if this will work. I hope so. Depends on how you're receiving the data from http call.
https://plnkr.co/edit/vMOCZRJ4Pwx4qfYhbvIg?p=preview

Comment: I changed result data to json, now working. but this is not I want. Anyway. I am so appreciate your kindness @OriolVives